# Convert very large decimal numbers to binary

Tags: fortran, decimal

For example, to convert an arbitrary long string of decimal numbers to binary. I think it's possible, once the length is known, starting from the left to right digits. I'm not able to find the way to do this. How can it be achieved?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to output a binary representation, or do you want to do calculations with the binary number?

Comment: *I think it's possible, once the length is known, starting from the left to right digits* I don't, not if the leftmost digit is the most significant. If it is possible, start with the first digits of `19*` and tell us the most significant binary digit(s) in the result.  Obviously the first digit in the binary number is `1` but what comes next ?

Comment: Tkoenig: A binary representation to save as a text is good for me.

Comment: this is really not a fortran or even a programming question, at least if (as it seems) you have no idea what algorithm to use. Suggest you try math.stackexchange.com, and put a little more effort into explaining what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use a library which already does what you want: [gmp](https://gmplib.org/).   It does not have Fortran bindings, but it is easy enough to call from Fortran using Fortran's [ISO C binding](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info) features and possibly a wrapper function.

If you have gcc installed, you already are using gmp; you may just have to install the relevant development files.

Using gmp, you would set your integer from a string value using `mpz_set_str` and convert it to another base using `mpz_get_str`.

No need to reinvent that particular wheel.